# Removing files from a directory based on file names in another file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a directory which contains multiple file (~1000) with names in the form of `ABC.txt, ABC.1.txt, ABC.2.txt, XYZ.txt, XYZ.1.txt` and so on.. I want to consider these names based on the first index if we split them by `.`. For example then names will be read as ABC XYZ and so on.. Then I want to remove those files for which these first index does not exist in an other (reference file). Given the file names mentioned above, let's say my other (reference file) only contains 1 name and that is XYZ. So the files that will be kept in the directory will be `XYZ.txt` and `XYZ.1.txt` and everything else which does not have the exact prefix as `XYZ` will be removed. I said exact because it might happen that there will be a file with name `XYZA.txt`, so there should be an exact match in order to keep that file.

Can anybody help me with this. Thank you very much.

EDIT: One directory contains all the files: `ABC.txt, ABC.1.txt, ABC.2.txt, XYZ.txt, XYZ.1.txt` and the reference file is in another directory as file name `reference.txt` and is a one-column file containing other directory's file (prefix)names as ABC, XYZ, CDE etc..

Comment: Add your file to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I have added the file names, can you please guide me how to do it. I am unable to understand your suggestion. Can you please elaborate it a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for f in *.*; 
do if grep -qF "${f%%.*}" file; 
   then echo "skip $f"; 
   else echo "rm $f"; fi; 
done
```

searches all files with a dot in file name, extract the prefix until the first dot, compare literally in the file with not to be deleted names, and echo the rm file command.  Make sure your file with names doesn't have a dot, otherwise it will be removed as well.

if looks fine remove `echo` before `rm`.